# if two sets of vectors are linearly independent; then a set containing all the vectors is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Say we have a set of vectors {a,b} and another set of vectors {c,d}. Both these sets are linearly independent. a,b,c,d are all *distinct* vectors. How would I prove that the set {a,b,c,d} is linearly independent?

---

What if all the vectors are in ℝ4

Comment: Why would you expect this?  Suppose, for example, that we were in $\mathbb R^2$?  Then your conclusion is impossible...  As a concrete counterexample say $c=2a,d=2b$.

Comment: If the statement was true, then $\mathbb{R}^2$ would have a basis consisting of $4$ vectors.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've added an edit that I forgot to put into the question. The vectors are in R4.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't, for example: $$\{(0,1), (1,0)\}, \{(0,4), (4,0)\}$$

Even if all the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^4$, 
$$\{(0,1,0,0), (1,0,0,0)\}, \{(0,4,0,0), (4,0,0,0)\}$$

Comment: I understand it now, regardless of the dimension, if we keep adding zeros to the vector it will be linearly dependent in that case. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Bob1123  
I understand it now, regardless of the dimension, if we keep adding zeros to the vector it will be linearly dependent in that case. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't linearly independent.

You lose linear independence if you introduce redundant elements (that is, elements which can be formed as linear combinations of existing elements).

Comment: I'm sorry. I've added an edit that I forgot to put into the question. The vectors are in R4.

Comment: @RacketBeginner, it doesn't matter whether the vectors are in R4 or not. The counterexamples and reasoning still works, just with a couple of more coordinates with 0's in them. The idea is that it is possible, just not always true.

Answer (score 1):

We can take this further. Suppose $\{a,b\} , \{b,c\} , \{c,a\}$ are all linearly independnet. That does not imply $\{a,b,c\}$ is a linearaly independent set.

Take $a=(1,0) , b=(0,1) , c=(1,1)$

Edit: for $\mathbb R ^4 $ you can just view these as a projection onto $\mathbb R ^2$ (just add another independent vector if you may).

Intuitively, I don't see how you can something "powerful" about a union of arbitrary sets of independent vectors. Meaning you will have to add more restrictions; perhaps the dimension of the space, orthogonality, independence in triplets etc...